# Reuse of mysql query

Tags: java, mysql

I have multiple queries, wherein i will do some tasks.

for Eg:

```
<pre>
select * from test 
where something
if check A
if check B
if check C
compare something.
For one table.
</pre>
```

like wise i have many other queries for different tables.

```
<pre>
select * from test 
where something
if check A
if check B
if check C
compare something.
</pre>

currently i am using reference. 

    select * from test 
    where something

<pre>
&lt;include refId="test"/&gt;
</pre>

<sql id="test">
if check A
if check B
if check C
compare something
</sql>
```

is there any other better ways in doing this. and also the return type of the query is a hash map.

i would like to know if we can create a function or a method where we can pass some values as column or row names and then do the following instead of writing multiple queries?

More Information:
actually i am looking for a way to write a query once and use it all the way without entering it many times, as i told u earlier i am currently using reference to do that. 
but i am looking for a way where i dont need to use different select statements and then call the include tag. instead i want to write a function where i can pass the table name or column name from a java controller class to the xml or query file. so it can intake the values and then consider those input and act accordingly.

like the above i have to perform or pull up detail from different tables but the condition is almost same in all the queries. 
so i want to create a function where i can send the table from where to select and what to select and then conditions should be general where i can pass the values and then it should do the wrk for all.

Example COde:

```
<select id="searchPatientAdmissionByDates" resultType="hashMap" parameterType="hashMap">
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(admission_details.PATIENT_ID)) AS CASECOUNT
    FROM admission_details,patient
    WHERE
    admission_details.PATIENT_ID = patient.id
    <if test="admissionDate !=null">
        AND
        FROM_DATE &gt;= #{admissionDate}
    </if>
    <if test="admissionDateThru !=null">
        AND
        FROM_DATE &lt;= #{admissionDateThru}
    </if>
    <if test="dischargeDate !=null">
        AND
        THRU_DATE &gt;= #{dischargeDate}
    </if>
    <if test="dischargeDateThru !=null">
        AND
        THRU_DATE &lt;= #{dischargeDateThru}
    </if>
</select>
```

this is a query and has some conditions. similar to this query there are many queries with same if conditions but different tables. 
so i want to create a function where i can pass the values and that function should operate for al the queries which has same conditions.

Comment: You can use case statement.

Comment: Thnx for the quick reply.

Comment: Please use tags to identify your programming language and/or platform so those who may know the answer are able to find the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that I have seen many people try to solve.

The general pattern I've seen is to dynamically create SQL queries by checking for a bunch of object properties.  Sort of like

```
UserSearchFilter filter = new UserSearchFlter().
filter.setFirstName("John");
filter.setJobTitle("CFO");

List<User> users = userDao.search(filter);
```

The DAO simply uses if statements against each known property, and if detected, adds in a WHERE clause accordingly.

That usually works well for a while.  Eventually, it becomes difficult to performance tune because there are so many paths through the code.

Sometimes, a particular filter is not best done through a where clause, but through a sub-query or inner join condition.  Sometimes, you need to conditionally join other tables if and only if a particular filter condition is used.  Sometimes, you need to use a `WITH` factor to pull out a bunch of records and then join them later in your query and that may perform better.

In such cases, you'll wish you had a separate fixed query for every condition.

Now, of course, a separate query for every little one-off can be just as bad for maintenance.  I have been on both sides of this, where I strugge to decipher what used to be elegant code but turned spaghetti code due to the number of conditions and where I have the same SQL in every little area, with no re-use.

Like most things in life, there is a healthy balance that you can strike.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i hope as of now i could move on with reference and try calling it where ever i need to use those conditions.

Comment: You may be able to reuse a few queries.  Don't be afraid to do it.  Just be careful that you don't make your code so flexible that it becomes difficult to maintain.